# input & Safari browser

Tags: form, safari

Собственно такой вопрос, при регистрации на сайте (Wordpress + ContactForm7) во всех браузерах проходит нормально, а в сафари вообще не работают input. Туда просто не пишется текст.
Вот сайт, на 2-м экране форма, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?
http://siar2084.beget.tech/

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fsiar2084.beget.tech%2F

Comment: В инспекторе есть action у формы....